# Substitution of variables in Laplacian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose we have a function $u\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x=cy$ for a given constant $c$.

How do I write $\Delta_x u(x) = \Delta_x [u(cy)]$ in terms of $\Delta_y$ and $u$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $x = cy$, by chain rule we have

$$\frac{ \partial }{\partial y^i} u(cy) = c \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}u(cy) $$

So

$$\Delta_y u(cy) = c^2 \Delta_x u(x)$$

Comment: Thanks, is there a typo in your first equation? Should not be a $u$ there on the right.

Comment: Yes, It is corrected.